# filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file in folder A and I'm trying to copy it to folder B using this code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    try {
        std::filesystem::path src("C:\\Projects\\test.txt")
        std::filesystem::path dst("C:\\Projects\\Notes");

        std::filesystem::copy(src, dst, std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    } catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The code compiles but it outputs an error when I run it.

```
filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists 
[C:\Projects\test.txt] [C:\Projects\Notes]
```

Is my usage of filesystem incorrect? Is this a bug of MinGW?

```
MinGW-w64 9.0.0
GCC Version 11.1
```

MinGW taken from http://winlibs.com/

My OS is Windows 10

Comment: It's hard to tell without a working example but I suspect `"C:\\Projects\\Notes"` may be a directory. The system or the library could be confused by this and give out an inaccurate error message.

Comment: Apparently it is indeed [a bug in MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/852/)

Comment: Please provide example which will also print error information. Provide also compiler version and platform. I can't reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/J6B2fyFzV4D35MWp

Comment: @MarekR See edit.

Comment: @dewaffled Would boost  fs work in this case?

Comment: @NO_NAME Yes, It's a dir that I'm pasting the file into..

Comment: @jeffbRTC Does it work when you give it a full path with the file name?

Comment: @NO_NAME I need to copy file into the folder. I don't want to copy the contents of file to an another file.

Comment: @NO_NAME You're correct. Turns out, I have to add file name too.  Very strange implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to give the file name and it doesn't automatically copy the file into the folder like with high level languages.

So,

```
    std::filesystem::path dst("C:\\Projects\\Notes");
```

becomes

```
    std::filesystem::path dst("C:\\Projects\\Notes\test.txt");
```